# Background worker attempt

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

This is how the function was originally:

```
    void fillLiguanea()
    {
        items = new List<string>();
        this.liguanea_Lane2TableAdapter.Fill(this.pharmaciesDataSet3.Liguanea_Lane2);
        try
        {

            string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Liguanea_Lane2";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string scode = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("code"));
                comboBox2.Items.Add(scode);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This is how it looks now taking into consideration background worker:

```
 private List <string> items;
    void fillLiguanea()
    {
        items = new List<string>();
        this.liguanea_Lane2TableAdapter.Fill(this.pharmaciesDataSet3.Liguanea_Lane2);
        try
        {

            string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Liguanea_Lane2";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string scode = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("code"));
                // comboBox2.Items.Add(scode);
                items.Add(scode);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Below are my background worker functions which have been edited to populate the comboBox in question, which is comboBox2. 
This is my back ground worker:

```
     private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        fillLiguanea();
    }
```

This is my RunWorkerCOmpleted:

```
  private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (comboBox4.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {


            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is where am I going wrong? what the code should do is populate comboBox2 from my database based on the selection of combox4's index. Currently nothing happens. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure comboBox4.SelectIndex really == 0?

Comment: Yes because currently there is only one value in that comboBox

Comment: Hmm...why not change the test to comboBox.SelectedIndex != -1

Comment: Or test if `comboBox.Items.Count == 1` instead.

Comment: Still doesn't work, am wondering if my code is structured correctly

Comment: Post how your background thread is invoked; that might shed some light.

Comment: How do i do this again? Through a break?

Comment: Did it..apparently it's not even executing the thread based on the selection in combox4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `BackgroundWorker` you can consider such pattern:

1. Handle `DoWork` event and call the time-consuming task there.
   **○** Keep in mind the event is raised in another thread different than UI thread, so if for any reason you want to do some UI code in the event you should use `Invoke` to make a thread safe call to a UI element.
   **○** Putting time-consuming UI tasks in the DoWork is useless. Because the task should be run in UI thread using `Invoke` and it will make the UI thread busy again.
2. You can handle `RunWorkerCompleted` event to perform some tasks after the work in `DoWork` got completed. For example after you load data in `DoWork`, you can use the loaded data in `RunWorkerCompleted` to fill a `ComboBox`.
3. You should call `RunWorkerAsync` method of the component to start processing `DoWork` event.
   ○ When an async task is running using an instance of the component you can not start another task using the same component, so to prevent exception you should check `this.backgroundWorker1.IsBusy` and if the component is not busy call the method.
4. The component has a good support for error reporting or progress changing or cancelling the execution. To learn more about the features, take a look at [documentations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1).
5. For .NET 4.5 and later, you can use [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) pattern to perform asynchronous tasks.

**Example**

I suppose you have a `LoadData` method currently:

```
public void LoadData()
{
    this.categoryTableAdapter.Fill(this.testDBDataSet.Category);
}
```

And you want to populate a control with data which you load using `LoadData`. So you can handle the `DoWork` and `RunWorkerCompleted` like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    LoadData();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, 
    RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.comboBox1.DataSource = this.testDBDataSet.Category;
    this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
}
```

Also you should call the `RunWorkerAsync` when you want the task get started, for example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: This is awesome.  On a bus reading.  How would I split up my fillLiguanea function into the background worker?

Comment: Updating the UI should rather be done in the OnProgressChanged event method because it preserves the UI Synchronisation context.

Comment: @user1810304 When you enabled reporting progress and when you have a progress, yes. But in other cases the `RunWorkerCompleted` is a good choice. For example when you load data from database you don't have a progress change so it's better to use `RunWorkerCompleted` or alternatively you can update UI at the end of `DoWork` method using an `Invoke`.

Comment: @Jevon **1)** Don't do UI tasks in `fillLiguanea` - Just load data. **2)** Then in `RunWorkerCompleted` use the data. **3)** Forget about that data reader approach, instead load data into a data table which you can use in another method. You should use the data table at form level. **4)** Don't use `Items.Add`, instead set `DataSource` and `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` of  `ComboBox`. (here display member seems to be enough)

Comment: Thank you reza, will look on it when am home and update you on my progress.  You should think about running in the upcoming elections.  :)

Comment: Am looking at this now. Forgive me in advance as this is my first ever attempt at background worker. I will attempt your solutions now

Comment: While I believe the post definitely answers your question, but you should not accept an answer before you read it carefully.

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Comment: I took our suggestions into consideration but was wondering can the doWork GUI aspect be formatted this way rather than splitting it up completely:

    `SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string scode = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("code"));

                    comboBox4.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        comboBox2.Items.Add(scode);
                    });
                    }
         
        }`

Comment: It can, but it's useless, that while makes the UI thread busy because you call a UI job using Invoke.

Comment: @Jevon You need to **1)** Read the answer **carefully** **2)** Implement a really simple example like I posted for you in this answer or the previous one. I'm sure if you read the answer carefully and create a really simple project to understand what's going on, you will solve all problems about the topic :) Your focus is on the goal while you also need to focus on the way to reach goal.

Comment: Ok I'll try  to be more understanding