ASP.NET VB code doesn't retrieve the same records like the similar MS Access VBA code (with the same criteria)
I am migrating from MS Access to ASP.NET. The following code should find the data for them exists a photo. In MS Access, it finds multiple rows, but in ASP.NET, it only returns one row (because the rows are all the same data (duplicates) only the pictures found are different).
It seems the asp.net make grouping and gives for the one row only one photo!
I don't know how to modify my ASP.NET VB code to catch all the rows with the existing photos.
Thanks in advance for any help!
Here is my code:
Protected Sub btnGetPhoto_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetPhoto.Click
    Dim connectionString As String = "myConnectionString"
    Dim sql As String = String.Empty
    Dim myRepDesList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    Dim myCategoryList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

    ' Handle input fields txtRepDescription and txtCategory
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRepDescription.Text) Then
        If txtRepDescription.Text.Contains(",") Then
            txtRepDescription.Text = txtRepDescription.Text.Replace(", ", ",")
        End If
        myRepDesList = txtRepDescription.Text.Split(","c).ToList()
    End If

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCategory.Text) Then
        If txtCategory.Text.Contains(",") Then
            txtCategory.Text = txtCategory.Text.Replace(", ", ",")
        End If
        myCategoryList = txtCategory.Text.Split(","c).ToList()
    End If

    ' Validate and parse DateFrom and DateTo
    Dim dateFrom As DateTime
    Dim dateTo As DateTime

    If Not DateTime.TryParse(txtMyDateFrom.Text.Trim(), dateFrom) OrElse Not DateTime.TryParse(txtMyDateTo.Text.Trim(), dateTo) OrElse dateFrom > dateTo Then
        lblMessage.Visible = True
        lblMessage.Text = "Invalid date range. Please correct it."
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        Return
    End If

    ' Construct the base SQL query
    sql = "SELECT RMANo, DateTested, RepairDescription, Category, Model, Rev, SN, DefectivePartNumber, DefectivePartLocation, Location, Customer, RequestCustomer, HasInvParentSN, ParentPartNumber, ParentSerialNumber, SYSModel, SYSSN, AppliedECO, TestResult, ReportID FROM vw_RMAItemView WHERE DateTested BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo AND ReportID <> -1"

    ' Add conditions dynamically
    If myRepDesList.Any() Then
        sql &= " AND RepairDescription IN (" & String.Join(", ", myRepDesList.Select(Function(x, i) $"@RepDes{i}")) & ")"
    End If

    If myCategoryList.Any() Then
        sql &= " AND Category IN (" & String.Join(", ", myCategoryList.Select(Function(x, i) $"@Category{i}")) & ")"
    End If

    ' Fetch data from the database
    Dim photoTable As New DataTable()

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", txtMyDateFrom.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", txtMyDateTo.Text)

        ' Add parameters for RepairDescription
        For i As Integer = 0 To myRepDesList.Count - 1
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@RepDes{i}", myRepDesList(i))
        Next

        ' Add parameters for Category
        For i As Integer = 0 To myCategoryList.Count - 1
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@Category{i}", myCategoryList(i))
        Next

        conn.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        photoTable.Load(reader)
        reader.Close()

        ' Add the myPhoto column to the DataTable
        If Not photoTable.Columns.Contains("myPhoto") Then
            photoTable.Columns.Add("myPhoto", GetType(String))
        End If

        ' Add photo links to the DataTable
        Dim rowsToRemove As New List(Of DataRow)()

        For Each row As DataRow In photoTable.Rows
            Dim location As String = row("Location").ToString()
            Dim reportID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(row("ReportID"))
            Dim repairPhotoURL As String = ""

            ' Retrieve photo URL using stored procedure
            Using photoCmd As New SqlCommand("GetRepairPhoto", conn)
                photoCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                photoCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", location)
                photoCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportID", reportID)

                Dim photoReader As SqlDataReader = photoCmd.ExecuteReader()
                If photoReader.HasRows Then
                    photoReader.Read()
                    repairPhotoURL = photoReader("RepairPhoto").ToString()
                End If
                photoReader.Close()
            End Using

            ' Assign the photo URL to the myPhoto column
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(repairPhotoURL) Then
                row("myPhoto") = repairPhotoURL
            Else
                rowsToRemove.Add(row) ' Mark the row for removal if no photo is available
            End If
        Next

        ' Remove rows with no photos
        For Each row As DataRow In rowsToRemove
            photoTable.Rows.Remove(row)
        Next
    End Using

    ' Bind the filtered DataTable to the GridView
    GridView1.DataSource = photoTable
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub


Why are the rows 'duplicates'? Why would same data associate with different images? There is no unique identifier?

Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40925043/how-to-load-gridview-image-from-direct-url-in-thread

ASP.NET is irrelevant to this problem. You're using ADO.NET to interact with the database and that code would be the same regardless of the type of application.

Well, the first issue of course is this example:
    Dim sMyList As String = "Dog, Cat, Horse"
    Dim strSQL As String =
        $"SELECT * FROM tblAnimals 
        WHERE Animal IN ({sMyList})"

    Debug.Print(strSQL)

Of course, the output from above is now this:
SELECT * FROM tblAnimals 
WHERE Animal IN (Dog, Cat, Horse)

But, as above shows, for text type of data, then any condition has to be surrounded by single (') quotes.
So, the correct syntax for above would have to be this:
SELECT * FROM tblAnimals 
WHERE Animal IN ('Dog', 'Cat', 'Horse')

So, your SQL syntax of course is incorrect, since each of the assumed values has to be surrounded by quotes. And I should point out even if doing this in MS-Access, then the same requirement in your SQL would exist. So, even with Access SQL then quotes around each element in the IN(...) clause is required. So, I would look at your previous VBA code closer to see how that code dealt with the required surrounding quotes for each element in the IN() clause.
Next up?
In web land, you NEVER under any circumstances want to take user input and concatenate the input into a SQL string. The reason of course is SQL injection. And thus, I suggest from day 1, you make GREAT efforts to avoid this issue, since if you don't, then after writing all kinds of code, you one day have to go back and rewrite all such code. While the Access engine can't execute multiple statements in a given SQL string, SQL server does allow as such, and multiple statements such as
SELECT * from tblHotels; DROP TABLE tblHotels

Means that BOTH statements will execute, and thus the table will be dropped. All it takes is one user to type in a ";SOME bad SQL here", and with your code concentration, you risking SQL injection.
Hence, for your fun and enjoyment, we have this common comic:

So, we need to deal with two issues:
1) deal with SQL injection - prevent this issue.
2) deal with that each text string needs surrounding quotes (')

So, I suggest the following code:
    Dim sql As String = String.Empty

    ' Validate and parse DateFrom and DateTo
    Dim dateFrom As DateTime
    Dim dateTo As DateTime

    If Not DateTime.TryParse(txtMyDateFrom.Text.Trim(), dateFrom) OrElse Not DateTime.TryParse(txtMyDateTo.Text.Trim(), dateTo) OrElse dateFrom > dateTo Then
        lblMessage.Visible = True
        lblMessage.Text = "Invalid date range. Please correct it."
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        Return
    End If

    ' Construct the base SQL query
    sql =
        "SELECT vw_RMAItemView.*, RepairPhoto FROM vw_RMAItemView
        LEFT JOIN tblRepairPhotos ON tblRepairPhotos.Location = vw_RMAItemView.Location
        AND tblRepairPhotos.ReportID = vw_RMAItemView.ReportID
        WHERE (DateTested BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo) AND (ReportID <> -1)
        AND (RepairPhoto IS NOT null) "


    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand

    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@DateFrom", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateFrom
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@DateTo", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateTo

    Dim sParm As String = ""

    Dim strExtraWhere As String = ""
    Dim pCount As Integer = 0

    If txtRepDescription.Text <> "" Then
        txtRepDescription.Text = Replace(txtRepDescription.Text, ", ", ",")

        For Each OneValue As String In txtRepDescription.Text.Split(",")
            If strExtraWhere <> "" Then strExtraWhere &= ","
            pCount += 1
            sParm = $"@P{pCount}"
            strExtraWhere &= sParm
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(sParm, SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = OneValue
        Next

        sql &= $" AND (RepairDescription IN({strExtraWhere}) ) "
    End If

    strExtraWhere = ""

    If txtCategory.Text <> "" Then
        txtCategory.Text = Replace(txtCategory.Text, ", ", ",")

        For Each OneValue As String In txtCategory.Text.Split(",")
            If strExtraWhere <> "" Then strExtraWhere &= ","
            pCount += 1
            sParm = $"@P{pCount}"
            strExtraWhere &= sParm
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(sParm, SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = OneValue
        Next

        sql &= $" AND (Catagory IN({strExtraWhere}) ) "
    End If

    cmdSQL.CommandText = sql & " ORDER BY SOME COLUMN(s) GOES HERE"

    ' Fetch data from the database
    Dim photoTable As DataTable

    photoTable = MyRstP(cmdSQL)

    ' Bind the filtered DataTable to the GridView
    GridView1.DataSource = photoTable
    GridView1.DataBind()

Some additional notes:
A text box on a web form can't be null - it will be "" (empty string), so you really don't need much more then a simple <> "" in your code.
Same goes for this:
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCategory.Text) Then
    If txtCategory.Text.Contains(",") Then
        txtCategory.Text = txtCategory.Text.Replace(", ", ",")
    End If
    myCategoryList = txtCategory.Text.Split(","c).ToList()
End If

You can replace above with
if txtCategory.Text <> "" then
   txtCategory.Text = txtCategory.Text.Replace(", ", ",")
End If

If there are no ", " in the string, then the replace will do nothing, so once again, the .Contains is not required.
Also, note closely when you create the SQL command object. The adding of parameters can occur 100% independent of the SQL for that command object. In effect, order or EVEN NO SQL in the command object does not prevent adding of parameters. You are free to add the SQL before, or after adding parameters. However, do NOT use AddWith, and ALWAYS use .Add, and use a STRONG typed define for the parameter.
And by adopting @Parameters for the "in clause", then we eliminate the need for quoting each parameter with "'" (single quotes). Not only does the code thus eliminate messy string concatenation with having to surround the values with a quotes ('), it is also SQL injection safe. So, a double bonus exists with this approach, and we don't have to care about surrounding quotes for say text/string values, or dates, but for numbers, then no quotes are required. With parameters this issue of requiring quotes (or not requiring) is automatic handled for you.
Also, if the query were to return say 100 rows, then you are WHACKING the server with 100 stored procedure calls (a very bad idea). So, the suggested "air code" above does a left join, and then we use a condition to filter out any rows that don't have a photo URL. In other words, do a left join to pull in the rows, but then filter out by using the where clause, since as noted, this can save 100 hits to the server when the query returns say 100 rows. That's simply too many round trips to SQL server, and far too heavy on the SQL Server.
Last but not least, in a global module, I tend to place the following two routines, since it becomes fast tiring to type in connection string and code to return a datatable. Hence, I have these two helper routines in a global module.
Public Function MyRstP(cmdSQL As SqlCommand) As DataTable
    ' general get any data from SQL command
    Dim strCon As String = My.Settings.TEST4

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(strCon)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function

and
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable
    ' general get any data from SQL

    Dim strCon As String = My.Settings.TEST4

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(strCon)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function

While the above is "air code", it should be close to working, and note the boatloads of coding we saved with above.
I also did suggest using SELECT * FROM the view you have, as once again, the fields you have can be setup in the view you have, and thus no real need to replicate all the columns in your in-line (code) SQL you have.

Thank you for the quick response, Albert. I don't understand this part "My.Settings.TEST4". What should I write instead of TEST4?

That's just my test connection string. So, open the project properties page, and then choose settings. You are then thus free to use the connection string builder. Hence, then in code, you are free to use My.Settings.dbCon (or whatever you called the connection string in settings. Hence it just returns your connection string (so, build your own connection string in settings). And personally having come from Access, then the MyRst, and MyrstP routines are of great help in writing code - in fact easier then even VBA to create a data table (which is much like a recordset in VBA).

Thanks Albert. I couldn't figure it out, sorry. I am new at asp.net, and some of the functions are totally new world. I'll work on it on Monday. I wish you happy weekend.

No worries. As I pointed out, you can elminate quite  bit of code, and for the most part, most of the code reads rather close to VBA. So, work your way though this. It's still mostly plain  vb code - and the syntax is not all that far off from VBA code. And I would try/test a sql query in SQL studio - get it working with the left join, since then that eliminates the need to run the store procedure code to pull in the other record, and with a left join, then the picture URL column just becomes another column of the data table.  So, play/test with the SQL query in SQL studio until it works
